# Filter results from a WMI Query

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

Using vbscript, how can I filter the output from a WMI Query? I want to return every local user account except for 2 which are the "Administrator" and "Visitor".

```
Set colUsers = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("select * from Win32_UserAccount where LocalAccount = True")
For Each objUser in colUsers
    WScript.Echo objUser.Name
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rewrite your [`WQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) sentence to

```
objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_UserAccount Where Name<>'Administrator' AND Name<>'Visitor' AND LocalAccount=True")
```

Comment: Thanks, RRUZ! Would you mind also teling me how I can also filter an additional account? The account name is SYSTEM_123456a7 however the number part of the name is different on each machine. I tried Name<>'SUPPORT*' but it didn't work.

Comment: You can use the `LIKE` operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392263%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I gave it a shot, but I can't get it to work with the <> used prior to exlcude the other accounts. If I don't use <> then the only account it returns is the system account :)

Comment: In order to get help, post a new question with your issue.